# Привести данные из таблицы в такую структуру ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Доброго времени суток. Дабы не загружать Вас лишней информацией, вкратце и с примерами, опишу в чём проблема. Дело в том, что с базы данных MySQL я получаю некоторые данные. Проблема в том, что их нужно привести к определенному виду массива, а я даже не представляю как.

У нас есть таблица в базе данных и все ячейки, которые отвечают определенной группе. К примеру, группе с ID №1 должны быть помещены в один ассоциативный массив.

Пример этой таблички:

[image: пример таблички]

А вот и пример массива этого:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'modname' => 'Lorem',

        'pricing' => array(
            '0' => 0.03,
            '1' => 0.15, 
            '2' => 0.50
        ),

        'names' => array(
            '0' => 'Lorems +0.03',
            '1' => 'Ipsum +0.15',
            '2' => 'Dolor +0.50'
        )

    ),

    array(
        'modname' => 'Ipsum',

        'pricing' => array(
            '0' => 0.08,
            '1' => 0.20, 
            '2' => 0.60
        ),

        'names' => array(
            '0' => 'Sie +0.08',
            '1' => 'A +0.20',
            '2' => 'Mat +0.60'
        )

    )

);
```

Так вот, пока даже нет представления, как это можно реализовать в коде. Как так ячейки по определенному ID Group помещать в массив? Можно использовать if-else, но как проделать это всё в массиве?

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

**UPD: Добавлю небольшой пример для лучшего понимания:**

Представьте магазин, в нем есть товар - кровати.

Есть цена за кровать, но есть "модификаторы", которые влияют на цену. К примеру: размер кровати, цвет кровати, размещение дополнительных полочек. Вот суть в том, чтобы с БД как-то значения вытягивать и группировать по ID. Т.е. цвета к цветам, полочки к полочкам, размеры к размерам. И группировать всё это нужно именно в ассоциативном массиве, так как на примере.

Comment: Нипанимаю, причём от слова "совсем". Почему именно эти записи (`'Lorem'`, `'Ipsum'`) выбраны для элементов массива `modname`? Тем более что в таблице значения `'Lorem'` нет в принципе...

Comment: @Akina я так думаю просто человек нашол бесплатный вриланс и сам не знает что спросить. Вопрос кординально расходиться с примером.

Comment: @Akina, рандомно имена забил. Представьте на секундочку магазин, в нем есть товар кровати. Есть цена за кровать, но есть "модификаторы", которые влияют на цену. К примеру: размер кровати, цвет кровати, размещение дополнительных полочек. 

Вот суть в том, чтобы с БД как-то значения вытягивать и группировать по ID. Т.е. цвета к цветам, полочки к полочкам, размеры к размерам.

Comment: Ну так постройте в запросе сортировку именно в том порядке, в каком надо помещать элементы в массив, и, получив данные, загоняйте в массив за один проход. Но вообще-то могли бы и поработать над качеством вопроса по СВОЕЙ проблеме... небось ответ такого же качества-то не понравится?

Comment: @Akina, по другом пока не знаю, как реализовать. Вот думал как-то может всё в одну ячейку, но это же распарсивать. В общем, суть в том, что есть эти "модификаторы" и надо их реализовать. Буду счастлив, если подскажите, в какую сторону думать.

Comment: @Felix Думать в сторону предоставления корректного тестового примера

Comment: во втором элементе массива `name` то наверное `Sie` должен быть? или я не понимаю тогда алгоритма выбора

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , ну вот, к примеру, похожий алгоритм: http://i.imgur.com/CX3diAB.jpg, в зависимости от выбора, к примеру "пол", меняется основная цена.

Comment: @teran, да, именно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим исходные данные уже извлечены и находятся в массиве `input`:

```
$input = [
           ['id_group' => 1, 'name' => "Lorem", 'price' => 0.03],
           ['id_group' => 2, 'name' => "Sie",   'price' => 0.08],
           ['id_group' => 1, 'name' => "Ipsum", 'price' => 0.15],
           ['id_group' => 1, 'name' => "Dolor", 'price' => 0.50],
           ['id_group' => 2, 'name' => "A",     'price' => 0.20],
           ['id_group' => 2, 'name' => "Mat",   'price' => 0.60],
    ];
```

очевидно, что обрабатывать мы их будем в цикле. Каждый раз, когда мы встречаем  новый `id_group` мы должны добавлять элемент в результирующий массив. При этом имя текущего элемента будет определять `name` группы.
После чего по номеру группы мы должны добавить элементы `pricing` и `names`.

```
$result = [];
foreach($input as $d){
    $gId = $d['id_group'];

    //новая группа
    if(!isset($result[$gId])){
        $result[$gId] = [
                'modname' => $d['name'],
                'pricing' => [],
                'names'   => [],
             ];
    }

    $result[$gId]['pricing'][] = $d['price'];
    $result[$gId]['names'][] = sprintf("%s %+.2f", $d['name'], $d['price']);
}
```

Искомый результат вывода:

```
Array (
[1] => Array
    (
        [modname] => Lorem
        [pricing] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0.03
                [1] => 0.15
                [2] => 0.5
            )

        [names] => Array
            (
                [0] => Lorem +0.03
                [1] => Ipsum +0.15
                [2] => Dolor +0.50
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [modname] => Sie
        [pricing] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0.08
                [1] => 0.2
                [2] => 0.6
            )

        [names] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sie +0.08
                [1] => A +0.20
                [2] => Mat +0.60
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ответ, то что нужно, но у меня появилась проблемка. 
Дело в том, что с Вашим массивом всё работает отлично, но с моим выходит то, что вовсе не подходит.
Вот скриншот моего массива: http://i.imgur.com/daK7R0H.jpg. Так вот, вместо желаемого получается вот такой массив: http://i.imgur.com/po7MAOl.jpg.
P.S. Да, знаю, что некоторые значения(id_group, id и т.д.) не вписал, но это пока без нужды, и на формирование массива не влияет, вроде бы.

Comment: Ой, так они же и одинаковой id_group, что-то я вообще уже, нужно поспать, похоже. Спасибо.